# How to Create custom Workflow in SharePoint online (not using SPD)

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, visual-studio-2015

i am working on SharePoint online and i have got one requirement of workflow which is almost 10-12 level.

if it is SharePoint on-premise then i can achieve it by sequential workflow  using visual studio. but i have no idea how to do the same in the SharePoint Online
Do i need to go by app model (SharePoint hosted/provider hosted app)?
if i will create app also how it will trigger the workflow automatically when a new item would be added on a SharePoint List.

eg: if i am creating a list item and List workflow it will be triggered when ever a new item will be created or item will be updated.

In My case Item created from List is also from different application using CSOM?

My question is how app will be triggered while creation/update of List item

Comment: please check my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

We cannot develop workflows via Visual Studio for SharePoint Online. Workflows developed via Visual Studio deploy as a full trust solution, which isn’t something you’re able to do in SPO.

The answer was available in the sharepoint  stackexchange question  [starting point for creating custom SharePoint Online workflows with Visual Studio](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128894/recomended-starting-point-for-creating-custom-sharepoint-online-workflows-with-v)

Some of the points from the link

For creating workflows you can use the APP model or you can use SharePoint Designer.

Visual Studio

If you are building complex workflows which can't be developed using SPD then your only option is to create an APP.

Hope the above link will help you

**Update:** While adding the workflow to the app, we will get the Configuration wizard to select the workflow type and condition to start the workflow, etc...  Please check the  article   [Create SharePoint 2013 Workflow App-Site Columns to Fully Deployed App using Visual Studio 2012](http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2013/05/25/how-to-create-sharepoint-2013-workflow-app-site-columns-to-fully-deployed-app-using-visual-studio-2012/) .

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have seen this all blog already you might thought only i want to create workflow using Visual studio, but i didn't mention any where that i want it to develop using visual studio. But any way, i have edited my question to better understanding, please see if u can give some suggestion.